# Highlight cells if appearing in another sheet with a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a simple button with a macro.

I have three Sheets in my excel file:

"VLS", "DTMS"and "Results"

I would like a macro which highlights the cells in column A in 'Results' if they appear in column A in VLS or DTMS respectively.

Is it possible to highlight the cells appearing in VLS with green and DTMS with blue?

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting for this?

Comment: Hi, thanks! - That would also work, but I would like to build it into a a button, so it can be used as a template for a team which are not comfortable with conditional formatting. So thay can hit the button and see the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code help you?

```
Sub test()
    Dim LastRowSheet1 As Integer
    Dim LastRowSheet2 As Integer
    Dim LastRowSheet3 As Integer
    LastRowSheet1 = Sheets("Results").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    LastRowSheet2 = Sheets("VLS").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    LastRowSheet3 = Sheets("DTMS").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Found = False

    For i = 1 To LastRowSheet1
        For j = 1 To LastRowSheet2
            If Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("VLS").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                '''Value found in sheet VLS => GREEN'''
                Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        For k = 1 To LastRowSheet3
            If Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("DTMS").Cells(k, 1).Value Then
                If Found = True Then
                    Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                   '''Value found in sheet VLS and DTMS => RED'''
                Else
                    Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                    '''Value found in sheet DTMS => BLUE'''
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
        Found = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

It loops through your sheet "Results" column A and check all the values of the two others sheets : first with the sheet VLS then with DTMS.

As soon as the same value is detected in VLS, it changes the color to GREEN. Then if the value is also in DTMS, it changes the color to RED or if it's only in DTMS it changes it in BLUE.

If it works, you can create a button and then affect this macro to it.